# Non-working selector in popup window

Tags: jquery, popup, selector

I have a form in popup which loads by ajax request. For example input:

```
  <input id="target" type="text" value="123">
```

And script:

```
  test = $('#target').val();
  console.log(test); //shows nothing
  test2 = $('input#target').val();
  console.log(test2); //shows 123
```

What can be the reason of such behaviour? Id of input is unique. Project is written on YII if it matters.

Comment: are you sure you have one element that have ID `target`, if you did `console.log($("#target").length);` what do you get ?

Comment: You can check if you have more than one element with id `target` with this code `$('[id=target]').length` . Check and share what it's logging in console.

Comment: check that you don't have same id to multiple elements and you tried the console after popup load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of error normally indicates that you have duplicate `id` attributes on your page, which is invalid. To test this use:

```
alert($("#target").length);
```

If you see 0, or 1, it's correct. If you see greater than 1 then you need to fix the duplicates.